# Chrome Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, select

**book_list.jsp**

```
<script>
    function setAction(val) {
        var v = val.value;
        alert(val.value);
         if (v== "name" || v == "sell"){
                 document.getElementById("order").value = val.value;
                alert(document.getElementById("order").value ); 
        }
        if (v == "asc" || v == "desc") {
             document.getElementById("asc").value = val.value;
                alert(document.getElementById("asc").value ); 
        }
    //document.move.submit();
        document.submit();
    }

</script>

<form action="book-list" method="get" name="">
<select id="order" name="order" onChange="setAction(this);">
    <option value="name">이름순</option>
    <option value="sell">판매순</option>
</select>
<select id="asc" name="asc" onChange="javascript:setAction(this);">
    <option value="asc">오름차순</option>
    <option value="desc">내림차순</option>
</select>
</form>
```

**book-list Servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("euc-kr");
    String type = "list";   
    String word = "";   
    BookList list = null;
    Book book = new Book();
    String pageNo = request.getParameter("PAGE_NO");
    String first_no = request.getParameter("FIRST_NO");
    String last_no = request.getParameter("LAST_NO");
    String category = request.getParameter("CATEGORY");

    String order = request.getParameter("order");
    String asc = request.getParameter("asc");

    if (pageNo != null) {
        list = book.readPage(Integer.parseInt(pageNo), type, word, category, order, asc);
    } else if (first_no != null) {
        list = book.readPrevPage(Integer.parseInt(first_no), type, word, category, order, asc);
    } else if (last_no != null) {
        list = book.readNextPage(Integer.parseInt(last_no), type, word, category, order, asc);
    } else {
        list = book.readPage(1, type, word, category, order, asc);
    }
    list.setPageNum(book.count(type, word, category));

    request.setAttribute("BOOK_LIST", list);
    RequestDispatcher rd
            = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp?BODY_PATH=booklist_body.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

Hi.
I got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function book-list:357

I want to send the selected value to book-list Servlet.
But it did not send. I use chrome developer, detector? Is it right?
But it throws the error..
How can i send the values of 2 select?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to be sent when calling `document.submit()`?

Comment: actually I want to be sent "name" "sell" "asc" "desc" one of this!
I dont know how to use javascript in jsp well...

Comment: So then you should select and submit the form. A `document` has no `.submit()` method.

Comment: then how to fix the code..?
function setAction(val) {
         if (v== "name" || v == "sell"){
                 document.move.order.value = val.value;
                 document.move.submit();
           }
<form action="book-list" method="get" name="move">
<select id="order" name="order" onChange="setAction(this);">
    <option value="name">이름순</option>
    <option value="sell">판매순</option>
</select>

I tried like this. but it didnt work..

Comment: OMG!!!!I got it! i fix it!!! it works now!! thank you...really thanks!